# Is it really impossible to unpickle a Python class if the original python file has been deleted?

Tags: python, pickle

Suppose you have the following:

### file = 'hey.py'

```
class hey:
    def __init__(self):
        self.you =1

ins = hey()

temp = open("cool_class", "wb")
pickle.dump(ins, temp)
temp.close()
```

Now suppose you delete the file hey.py and you run the following code:

```
pkl_file = open("cool_class", 'rb')
obj = pickle.load(pkl_file)
pkl_file.close()
```

You'll get an error.  I get that it's probably the case that you can't work around the problem of if you don't have the file hey.py with the class and the attributes of that class in the top level then you can't open the class with pickle.  But it has to be the case that I can find out what the attributes of the serialized class are and then I can reconstruct the deleted file and open the class.  I have pickles that are 2 years old and I have deleted the file that I used to construct them and I just have to find out what what the attributes of those classes are so that I can reopen these pickles

#####UPDATE

I know from the error messages that the module that originally contained the old class, let's just call it 'hey.py'.  And I know the name of the class let's call it 'you'.  But even after recreating the module and building a class called 'you' I still can't get the pickle to open.  So I wrote this code on the `hey.py` module like so:

```
class hey:
    def __init__(self):
        self.hey = 1

    def __setstate__(self):
        self.__dict__ = ''
        self.you = 1
```

But I get the error message: TypeError: **init**() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

#########UPDATE 2:

I Changed the code from

```
class hey:
```

to

```
class hey():
```

I then got an AttributeError but it doesn't tell me what attribute is missing.  I then performed

```
obj= pickletools.dis(file)
```

And got an error on the pickletools.py file here

```
def _genops(data, yield_end_pos=False):
    if isinstance(data, bytes_types):
        data = io.BytesIO(data)

    if hasattr(data, "tell"):
        getpos = data.tell
    else:
        getpos = lambda: None

    while True:
        pos = getpos()
        code = data.read(1)
        opcode = code2op.get(code.decode("latin-1"))
        if opcode is None:
            if code == b"":
                raise ValueError("pickle exhausted before seeing STOP")
            else:
                raise ValueError("at position %s, opcode %r unknown" % (
                                 "<unknown>" if pos is None else pos,
                                 code))
        if opcode.arg is None:
            arg = None
        else:
            arg = opcode.arg.reader(data)
        if yield_end_pos:
            yield opcode, arg, pos, getpos()
        else:
            yield opcode, arg, pos
        if code == b'.':
            assert opcode.name == 'STOP'
            break
```

At this line:

```
code = data.read(1)
```

saying: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'`

I will now try the other methods in the pickletools

###########  UPDATE 3

I wanted to see what happened when I saved an object composed mostly of dictionary but some of the values in the dictionaries were classes.  This is the class that was saved:

so here is the class in question:

```
class fss(frozenset):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(frozenset, self).__init__()

    def __str__(self):
        str1 = lbr + "{}" + rbr
        return str1.format(','.join(str(x) for x in self))
```

Now keep in mind that the object pickled is mostly a dictionary and that class exists within the dictionary. After performing

```
obj= pickletools.genops(file)
```

I get the following output:

[image](https://ibb.co/wrmNwcP)

[image2](https://ibb.co/R23RPhW)

I don't see how I would be able to construct the class referred to with that data if I hadn't known what the class was.

############### UPDATE #4

@AKK

Thanks for helping me out.  I am able to see how your code works but my pickled file saved from 2 years ago and whose module and class have long since been deleted, I cannot open it into a bytes-like object which to me seems to be a necessity.

So the path of the file is

```
file ='hey.pkl' 
pkl_file = open(file, 'rb')
x = MagicUnpickler(io.BytesIO(pkl_file)).load()
```

This returns the error:

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not '_io.BufferedReader'
```

But I thought the object was a bytes object since I opened it with `open(file, 'rb')`

############ UPDATE #5

Actually, I think with AKX's help I've solved the problem.

So using the code:

```
pkl_file = open(name, 'rb')
x = MagicUnpickler(pkl_file).load()
```

I then  created two blank modules which once contained the classes found in the save pickle, but I did not have to put the classes on them.  I was getting an error in the file `pickle.py` here:

```
def load_reduce(self):
    stack = self.stack
    args = stack.pop()
    func = stack[-1]
    try:
        stack[-1] = func(*args)
    except TypeError:
        pass
dispatch[REDUCE[0]] = load_reduce
```

So after excepting that error, everything worked.  I really want to thank AKX for helping me out.  I have actually been trying to solve this problem for about 5 years because I use pickles far more often than most programmers.  I used to not understand that if you alter a class then that ruins any pickled files saved with that class so I ran into this problem again and again.  But now that I'm going back over some code which is 2 years old and it looks like some of the files were deleted, I'm going to need this code a lot in the future.  So I really appreciate your help in getting this problem solved.

Comment: Using the standard pickle module, the .py must be available on the machine doing the unpickling. The pickle file has a reference to the class - it tells the unpickler to load the module and create class instances. It does not pass the class source code itself.

Comment: `pickletools.dis` and `pickletools.genops` may help read what's in there. https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickletools.html

Comment: Thanks, but pickletools did not enable me to read a pickle file which serialized a class whose file has long since been deleted.

Comment: It can give you the data, but perhaps not easily consumed. Another option is to write a new module of the same name and class names. Those classes could just be dummies that implement `def __setstate__(self, state)` and save the state information, which will be the values of the original saved objects. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#object.__setstate__.

Comment: See update.....

Comment: Your update seems to imply your new `hey`'s `__init__` does not have the same signature the original had. If you can, please show us what `python -m pickletools` outputs for your file?

Comment: See update .....

Comment: @bobsmith76 `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'` stems from you trying to pass in a string to a function that expects a filelike object. Can you please try running `python -m pickletools cool_class`, but for your original problematic pickle file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, with a bit of hacking and magic, sure, you can hydrate missing classes, but I'm not guaranteeing this will work for all pickle data you may encounter; for one, this doesn't touch the `__setstate__`/`__reduce__` protocols, so I don't know if they work.

Given a script file (`so72863050.py` in my case):

```
import io
import pickle
import types
from logging import Formatter

# Create a couple empty classes. Could've just used `class C1`,
# but we're coming back to this syntax later.
C1 = type('C1', (), {})
C2 = type('C2', (), {})

# Create an instance or two, add some data...
inst = C1()
inst.child1 = C2()
inst.child1.magic = 42
inst.child2 = C2()
inst.child2.mystery = 'spooky'
inst.child2.log_formatter = Formatter('heyyyy %(message)s')  # To prove we can unpickle regular classes still
inst.other_data = 'hello'
inst.some_dict = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}

# Pickle the data!
pickle_bytes = pickle.dumps(inst)

# Let's erase our memory of these two classes:

del C1
del C2

try:
    print(pickle.loads(pickle_bytes))
except Exception as exc:
    pass  # Can't get attribute 'C1' on <module '__main__'> – yep, it certainly isn't there!
```

we now have successfully created some pickle data that we can't load anymore, since we forgot about those two classes. Now, since [the unpickling mechanism is customizable](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/pickle.html#pickle.Unpickler), we can derive a magic unpickler, that in the face of certain defeat (or at least an AttributeError), synthesizes a simple class from thin air:

```
# Could derive from Unpickler, but that may be a C class, so our tracebacks would be less helpful
class MagicUnpickler(pickle._Unpickler):
    def __init__(self, fp):
        super().__init__(fp)
        self._magic_classes = {}

    def find_class(self, module, name):
        try:
            return super().find_class(module, name)
        except AttributeError:
            return self._create_magic_class(module, name)

    def _create_magic_class(self, module, name):
        cache_key = (module, name)
        if cache_key not in self._magic_classes:
            cls = type(f'<<Emulated Class {module}:{name}>>', (types.SimpleNamespace,), {})
            self._magic_classes[cache_key] = cls
        return self._magic_classes[cache_key]
```

Now, when we run that magic unpickler against a stream from the aforebuilt `pickle_bytes` that plain ol' `pickle.loads()` couldn't load...

```
x = MagicUnpickler(io.BytesIO(pickle_bytes)).load()
print(x)
print(x.child1.magic)
print(x.child2.mystery)
print(x.child2.log_formatter._style._fmt)
```

prints out

```
<<Emulated Class __main__:C1>>(child1=<<Emulated Class __main__:C2>>(magic=42), child2=<<Emulated Class __main__:C2>>(mystery='spooky'), other_data='hello', some_dict={'a': 1, 'b': 2})
42
spooky
heyyyy %(message)s
```

Hey, magic!

Comment: See update ........

Answer (score 1):

The error in function load_reduce(self) can be re-created by:

```
class Y(set):
    pass


pickle_bytes = io.BytesIO(pickle.dumps(Y([2, 3, 4, 5])))

del Y

print(MagicUnpickler(pickle_bytes).load())
```

AKX's answer do not solve cases when the class inherit from base classes as set, dict, list,...